# assertRaises doesn't catch errors

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have this script

```
import unittest,itertools,random

##testclass
class Testcomb(unittest.TestCase):

     def test_input(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError,calculate_combinations,dict(comb1), 5)

def calculate_combinations(combin,target):
    counter = 0
    for L in range(0, len(combin)+1):
      for subset in itertools.combinations(combin, L):
        if sum(subset) == target: counter= counter+1
    return counter

comb1=[1,2,3,4]


if __name__=='__main__': unittest.main()
```

but the `self.assertRaises(TypeError,calculate_combinations,dict(comb1), 5)` does not intercept the exception giving me this error:

```
E..
======================================================================
ERROR: test_input (__main__.Testcomb)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "total_combination.py", line 25, in test_input
    self.assertRaises(TypeError,calculate_combinations,dict(comb1), 5)
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception that makes your test fail is triggered by the `dict(comb1)` part of the assertion.

```
>>> comb1=[1,2,3,4]
>>> dict(comb1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

On the contrary, the `assertRaises` will return `True` only if it is the callable (in your case `calculate_combinations`) to trigger it.

HTH!

Comment: @kurojishi Even the best ones sometime fail! ;) If it solves your issue, please mark answer as accepted. :)